# Networking use wireshark to capture android mobile (unrooted) network calls

Tags: android, macos, networking, wireshark

I am new on Wireshark, I want to capture the network calls of android devices on Wireshark. I have gone through many sites and they have mentioned to download shark for mobile which works on rooted device only. So i want to know if there is a way to track the calls without rooting the device.
Moreover does

> tshark commmand

(command line for Wireshark) can be used to track the network calls on my android device as it catches the network calls of the desktop only. What filter can be applied to Wireshark so that i can see my mobile device network calls. I am using Macbook and all my devices connected to same network.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something else to work around.

The point is to use your computer as a proxy for the device then you can catch the network calls on Wireshark.

You can use some software that provide proxy feature(I use Charles and it's really great and it can catch network calls itself already) then turn to your device setting and set it's proxy on your computer. Then turn on the Wireshark and you can catch the network calls.

hope that helps :)

Comment: I have used burp suite and Charles also and they good in catching the network calls. But i need to check if it is possible to run those using some command line as with Wireshark which provides "tshark" command line interface which can be helpful in automation also.